# How exactly does call symput work - trying to create an iterator with help of call symput

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, iterator

I am writing the code that is modifying an array declared in previous data step. Since it is a new datastep old indexes won't work. I thought I could use an iterator with help of call symput function.
I was trying assign 0 value for each MID_(i) array element where month < "i" so I came up with code:

```
data want;
set summary;
do i=1 to &MAX_MONTH.;
    call symputx('iterator',i);
    if MONTH < &iterator. then MID_&iterator. = 0;
end;run;
```

And it doesn't work. I was experimenting with the code to debug it and inserted a constant value instead of "i":

```
data want;
set summary;
do i=1 to &MAX_MONTH.;
    call symputx('iterator',7);
    if MONTH < &iterator. then MID_&iterator. = 0;
end;run;
```

To confuse me even more, this code only works once. When I change '7' for other number the result stays the same until I reset SAS and after that it will work with changed value, but still - only once.

What happens here? What am I not understanding? How do I create a working iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro processor does its work converting the macro expressions into text first. So `&MAX_MONTH` and `&iterator` have already been replaced by their values before SAS even begins to compile the data step, and definitely before it has a chance to run either the CALL SYMPUTX() or the IF statement.

So if MAX_MONTH had a value of 12 and ITERATOR had a value of 7 then you ran this data step:

```
data want;
  set summary;
  do i=1 to 12;
    call symputx('iterator',i);
    if MONTH < 7 then MID_7 = 0;
  end;
run;
```

Which is the same as just running:

```
data want;
  set summary;
  if MONTH < 7 then MID_7 = 0;
  i=13;
run;
%let iterator=12;
```

The ARRAY statement is the data step method to use to reference a variable by its position in a list.  So if you want to reference variables with names like MID_1, MID_2, etc then define an array and use an index into the array.  You could still use your MAX_MONTH macro variable to define the set of variables to include in the array.

So perhaps you meant to run something like this:

```
data want;
  set summary;
  array mid_ [&max_month] ;
  do index=month+1 to dim(mid_);
    MID_[index] = 0;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comprehensive answer. However I have to ask one more question.
If I declare a new array, like you suggested, won't it completely overwrite my previous values that were stored before? I wanted to perform further calculations on that array, not erase all the values completely.

Comment: Adding a variable to an array does not make any change to the variable.  An array is  just a tool for referencing variables.  If the variables listed (or implied as in my example) do not exist they are created, but if they already exist they are just used as is.

Answer (score 1):

`symput` and `symputx` create macro variables after the data step ends. The macro variables being created cannot be accessed within the same data step. Each time `symput` is called, the macro variable that will be output at the end is updated.

Per the `call symput` [documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p09y28i2d1kn8qn1p1icxchz37p3.htm#p1cndmyuohxh1xn1ggnwqzg6j0u7):

> You cannot use a macro variable reference to retrieve the value of a
> macro variable in the same program (or step) in which SYMPUT creates
> that macro variable and assigns it a value.
>
> You must specify a step
> boundary statement to force the DATA step to execute before
> referencing a value in a global statement following the program (for
> example, a TITLE statement). The boundary could be a RUN statement or
> another DATA or PROC statement.

You do not need to use `symput` to achieve your goal. `i` is already iterating and you can use it if you create a new array of your `mid_` variables.

```
data want;
    set summary;
    array mid_[&MAX_MONTH.];

    do i=1 to dim(mid_);
        if MONTH < i then MID_[i] = 0;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend sticking entirely with arrays and if your variables have a naming convention you don't need anything else.

I don't have your data but I wonder if a simplification like this could work as well.

```
data want;
    set summary;
    array mid_[*] mid_:;

    do i=1 to month-1;
         MID_[i] = 0;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Stu, Tom, and Reeza have all answered the question with the way you should do this.

However, for completeness, here is how you could do this using macro variables: by using macro `%do` as well.  This is *not* the right way to do your exact problem, but there are problems that might require this method.

```
%let max_month=12;

data summary;
  do month = 1 to 12;
    output;
  end;
run;

%macro do_months(max_month);
data want;
    set summary;
    %do i=1 %to &MAX_MONTH.;        
        if MONTH < &i. then MID_&i. = 0;
    %end;
run;
%mend do_months;

%do_months(max_month=12);
```

Here if you turn on `options mprint;` you can see what SAS is doing: it's making 12 `if` statements for you, each of which has a different value for the iterator and for the mid_ variable.  All 12 are executed every time through the data step.  It's not nearly as efficient as the array solution, and it's much harder to debug, so don't do it unless you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Tom gave good advice on how to solve you problem. However no one explained how call symputx() works: answer by Stu Sztukowski is partially incorrect since it interprets the SAS documentation in a wrong way.

There are two languages: SAS Base (data step, proc sql, etc.) and SAS Macro (%let, %put, &var, etc.). So there are two worlds: SAS Base world and SAS Macro world. You can exchange data between these two worlds using specific functions.

**1. Access SAS Base world from SAS Macro.**
You can execute most of SAS Base functions using specific macro `%sysfunc()`. Example:

```
%let mvSrc = there    are multiple  blanks;
%let mvVar = %qsysfunc(compbl(%nrbquote(&mvSrc)));
%put &=mvVar; /* prints MVVAR=there are multiple blanks */
```

It is a good practice to prefix Macro Variables with mv.
Also I used macro `%nrbquote()` to be able to process strings with specific to SAS Macro symbols like brackets, commas, quotes, ampersands, etc. It is not required here but it is a good practice too.

**2. Access SAS Macro world from SAS Base code.**

```
data _null_;
    call symputx('mvVar', 'hey!', 'g'); /* 1 */
    var = symget('mvVar');              /* 2 */
    put var=;                           /* 3 */

    call symputx('mvVar', 'whats' up?', 'g');
    var = symget('mvVar');
    put var=;
run;
```

The output is as follows:

```
hey!
what's up?
```

How it works:

1. Create macro variable `mvVar` in global scope with value hey!.
2. Read closest (local, one of calling macro, ..., global) macro variable `mvVar` into data step variable `var`.
3. Print the value.

Should one use those functions? As for call symputx() the answer is yes, you have to use it to put data into macro world. As for symget(), the answer is sometimes you should use it, sometimes it is easier to do with simple macro variable substitution, i.e. `var = "&mvVar";`. The problem with substitution is that it won't work when macro variable contains double quotes. For example, following code

```
%let mvVar = hey, "Mr X"!;
data _null_;
    var = "&mvVar";
run;
```

turns into erroneous code:

```
data _null_;
    var = "hey, "Mr X"!"; /* error! */
run;
```

Also remember that substitution occurs only once, before data step is compiled and hence before it is executed. The following code

```
%let mvVar = hello;
data _null_;
    var = "&mvVar";
    put var=;

    call symputx('mvVar', 'yes?', 'g');
    var = "&mvVar";
    put var=;
run;
```

turns into

```
data _null_;
    var = "hello";
    put var=;

    call symputx('mvVar', 'yes?', 'g');
    var = "hello";
    put var=;
run;
```

and prints

```
hello
hello
```

SAS also includes a mechanism to execute macro code inside a data step. The mechanism uses `dosubl()` function or `call execute()` routine. The mechanism is a duck tape, it is hard to understand, it works in a non intuitive way and **must never be used. Abosultely never. Ever.**

Comment: Your explanation of the meaning of the symbol table option to CALL SYMPUTX() is confused.  The G option means to write it into the GLOBAL symbol table.  The L option means to write it into the most local symbol table.  The F option (or just not using the third parameter) means to write to the most local existing macro variable, or create a new macro variable in the most local symbol table if no such macro variable exists.  The most local could be the GLOBAL space, such as when called in open code instead of in a macro.

Comment: Yes, it may seem confused, but that's how SAS works: if you set G option and have macro variable in local symbol table then you update variable in local symbol table! I checked that in SAS 9.4M6.

Comment: Nope.  If you use the G option the GLOBAL version of the macro variable is changed (or created). The value of the LOCAL version is unchanged by the CALL SYMPUTX() function call.

Comment: Sorry, checked again, misinterpreted result.

Comment: For more fun going the other way (reading macro variable that is NOT the most local) check out:  https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/symget.sas