# Put with macro variable as format

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset with a variable called pt with observations 8.1,8.2,8.3 etc and a variable called mean with values like 8.24 8.1 8.234 etc. Which are paired with each other.

I want to be able to set my put informat to the formats from the variable num.

I get the errors "Expecting an arithmetic expression"
"the symbol is not recognized and will be ignored" and "syntax error" from my code. (underlining the &fmt. part)

```
if pt=&type;

call symput("fmt",pt);

fmt_mean = putn(mean,&fmt.);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You usually can't access macro variables in the same step they're created, in that case you can use the value already defined. Can you illustrate your issue with a more representative example?

Comment: If your example is correct and representative the following would work: `fmt_mean = putn(mean, pt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro processor's work is done before SAS compiles and runs the data step.  So trying to place the value into a macro variable and then use it immediately to generate and execute SAS code will not work.

But since you are using the PUTN() function it can use the value of an actual variable, so there is no need to put the format into a macro variable.

```
fmt_mean = putn(mean,pt);
```

Comment: Did not see your answer when started writing my own xD

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your data set and data step. Your description is hard to understand.

However the solution seems to be simple: do not use macro variables! You don't need them here. Unlike `put()` function which expect format know at compile time (that is when you can use macro variables) its analog `putn()` expects second argument to be variable. Of course, it works a little slower due to that permittance. So your code can look like that:

```
data ...;
    set ...(keep=mean pt);
    fmt_mean = putn(mean, pt);
run;
```

where `pt` variable maybe numeric, i.e. 8.2, or character, i.e. '8.2'.

If you want to understand how SAS macro works and what `call symput` does look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69979074/7864377